# Is there a package for object-relational mapping in R?

Tags: r, orm, dplyr, rmysql

(By object-relational mapping, I mean what is described here: [Wikipedia: Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).)

Here is how I could imagine this work in R : a kind of "virtual data frame" is linked to a database, and returns the results of SQL queries when accessed. For instance, `head(virtual_list)` would actually return the results of `(select * from mapped_table limit 5)` on the mapped database.

I have found this [post by John Myles White](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/01/05/announcing-r-orm-a-pure-r-object-relational-mapper/), but there seems to have been no progress in the last 3 years.

Is there a working package that implements this ?

If not,

1. Would it be useful ?
2. What would be the best way to implement it (S4 ?) ?

Comment: Oracle has a product that does this in R...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The very recent package `dplyr` is implementing this (amongst other amazing features).

Here are illustrations from the examples of function `src_mysql()`:

```
# Connection basics ---------------------------------------------------------
# To connect to a database first create a src:
my_db <- src_mysql(host = "blah.com", user = "hadley",
  password = "pass")
# Then reference a tbl within that src
my_tbl <- tbl(my_db, "my_table")

# Methods -------------------------------------------------------------------
batting <- tbl(lahman_mysql(), "Batting")
dim(batting)
colnames(batting)
head(batting)
```

Comment: dplyr doesn't support persisting objects to the database (you still have to write INSERT INTO statements). There are ways to do it, but they aren't recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26784801/3910619

Comment: This is not an ORM approach. This simply pulls a table from the database and converts it to a data.frame/tbl. A proper ORM maps entries, including their relationships, of the database to objects/classes in the programming language.

Answer (score 7):

There is an old unsupported package, [SQLiteDF](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SQLiteDF/), that does that.  Build it from source and ignore the numerous error messages.

```
> # from example(sqlite.data.frame)
>
> library(SQLiteDF)
> iris.sdf <- sqlite.data.frame(iris)
> iris.sdf$Petal.Length[1:10] # $ done via SQL
 [1] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like John Myles White he's given up on it.

There is a bit of a workaround explained [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-November/180357.html).

Answer (score 1):

As an experienced R user, I would not use this. First off, this 'virtual frame' would be slow to use, since you constantly need to synchronize between R memory and the database. It would also require locking the database table, since otherwise you have unpredictable results due to other edits happening at the same time.

Finally, I do not think R is suited for implementing a different evaluation of `promise` objects. Doing `myFrame$foo[ myFrame$foo > 40 ]` will still fetch the full `foo` column, since you cannot possible implement a full translation scheme from R to SQL.

Therefore, I prefer to load a dataframe() from a query, use it, and write it back to the database if required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with the memory and locking. That could be a problem depending on the project. Regarding the example of the line selection: a full translation scheme might not be possible, but are least a lot of common manipulations should be feasible (the line selection in the example would be trivial for instance)...

Comment: The line selection example is trivial for you. Let's push this further: top 10% percentile? Random n=100 sampling? etc... In practice, the limits of this are very quickly reached.

Answer (score 1):

Next to the various driver packages for querying DBs (DBI, RODBC,RJDBC,RMySql,...)
and dplyr, there's also sqldf https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/

This will automatically import dataframes into the db & let you query the data via sql. At the end the db is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be useful. R is not a real OOP language. The "central" data structure in R is the data frame.  No need for Object-Relational Mapping here.What you want is a mapping between SQL tables and data frames and the RMySQL and RODBC provide just that :

> **dbGetQuery** to return the results of a query in a data frame and **dbWriteTable** to insert data in a table or do a bulk update ( from a data frame).

Comment: I disagree with this viewpoint: no useful language is "purely" of any particular type.  R claims to be a functional language, but it also allows for many side effects.  R should have the means to create an ORM, and I'm glad that `dplyr` stepped up.

Answer (score 0):

The most similar could be dbplyr.
In R you work with tables, not rows.