# Is it possible to insert (add) a row to a SQLite db table using dplyr package?

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I am new to the database connection capabilities of dplyr package, but I am very interested in using it for an SQLite connection. I followed [this tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) and created an SQLite database (my_db)

```
my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = T)
```

and inserted a dataframe (df) as a table (my_table) of this database.

```
copy_to(my_db,df,"my_table")
```

Now I want to insert new rows in this table. I tried something like this (and yes I must admit it doesn't even look like promising... but I still gave it a try):

```
collect(build_sql("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (",newdf,")", con=my_db))
```

Does anyone know if adding rows to an existing sqlite db table is even possible using dplyr? Or how would you deal with this problem? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Package `sqldf` is worth a check. It allows easy interaction with dataframes and sql tables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568182/is-it-possible-to-insert-add-a-row-to-a-sqlite-db-table-using-dplyr-package/26784801#comment80776297_26784801 and https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3120#issuecomment-339034612   -- it is somewhat possible, but awkward, and recommended against.  Use DBI:: instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* perform SQL operations on a database/table created via `dplyr`, but you have to revert to RSQLite/DBI calls and change how you made the database/table:

```
library(dplyr)

my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create=TRUE) 
copy_to(my_db, iris, "my_table", temporary=FALSE) # need to set temporary to FALSE

# grab the db connection from the object created by src_sqlite
# and issue the INSERT That way

res <- dbSendQuery(my_db$con, 
                   'INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, "new")')
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Do you think it is possible to add entire tables to an existing one as well, instead of just one row? Or is that purely an SQL question?

Comment: okay, I guess I can use the dbWriteTable function instead of dbSendQuery. Though I keep on getting this message: "In sqliteWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...) : unable to begin transaction".

Comment: I was too quick with my comments. Very recently there was an RSQLite update that I hadn't installed yet. Everything works as planned now. Thanks again hrbrmstr!

Comment: Instead of constructing the query by hand, it would be better to use `dbWriteTable(append = TRUE)`

Answer (score 57):

No, you *can* do this all within `dplyr`.

```
require(dplyr)

my_db <- src_sqlite( "my_db.sqlite3", create = TRUE)                 # create src
copy_to( my_db, iris, "my_table", temporary = FALSE)                 # create table
newdf = iris                                                         # create new data
db_insert_into( con = my_db$con, table = "my_table", values = newdf) # insert into
```

Comment: I think it's db_insert_into( con = my_db$con, table = "my_table", **values** = newdf)

Comment: reinserting iris worked for me: `db_insert_into( con = my_db$con, table = "my_table", values = iris)`

Comment: Per the help docs, `db_write_table(...,append=TRUE)` is intended to replace the deprecated `db_insert_into()` function, but as of 2017-09-22, it does not appear to work with sqlite3.

Comment: You _can_, but you shouldn't. dplyr is designed specifically for retrieving data from databases, not modifying in place. 

This answer uses internal functions - I **strongly** recommend against using these functions.

Answer (score 17):

In [this newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/IsRVJWoMPe4). 
  Hadley explained the purpose of the function `dplyr::copy_to()`.
It is intended to create temporary test tables.
The email exchange ends by suggesting to use `RMySQL::dbWriteTable()` 
to append data to an existing table. The same applies to SQLite databases, as explained in the accepted answer above.

To append a data frame `dtf` which has the same column names as an existing database table, I used:

```
library(RMySQL)
DB <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="usename", host="localhost",
                   password="***", dbname="dbname")
dbWriteTable(DB, "tablename", dtf, append=TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: sorry I realise your question was about adding rows to an SQLite table. I landed here during my search. Maybe I leave my answer for the moment.

Comment: Thanks anyhow! It's interesting additional information.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason I use `dplyr` to write into a database is that I do not want to switch between languages mid code. For your question the best solution I think is to use the `db_insert_into()` function of `dplyr` as illustrated by [StatSandwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568182/is-it-possible-to-insert-add-a-row-to-a-sqlite-db-table-using-dplyr-package/26784801#26784801)

Comment: You need not switch to SQL, but you can use `DBI::dbWriteTable()` etc. in R.