# Adding rows to SQLite data base using dplyr

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I'm trying to add rows to a SQLite data base using dplyr. Based on StatSandwich's answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568182/is-it-possible-to-insert-add-a-row-to-a-sqlite-db-table-using-dplyr-package) I would have thought that the following may work:

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- filter(mtcars, cyl == 6)
data2 <- filter(mtcars, cyl == 4)

my_db <- src_sqlite(path="Test.DB", create = TRUE)
copy_to(my_db, data1, temporary = FALSE)
db_insert_into(my_db, table=data1, values=data2) # Error
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("db_insert_into") : 
>     no applicable method for 'db_insert_into' applied to an object of class "c('src_sqlite', 'src_sql', 'src')"

Would anyone be able to point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, Philipp

Comment: hi, your attempt differs from @StatSandwich by quite a bit...try copy_to(my_db, data1, "mtcarsTable", temporary = FALSE);
db_insert_into(my_db$con, table="mtcarsTable", values=data2) #

Comment: or just to fix that error you should use: db_insert_into(my_db$con, table="data1", values=data2)

Comment: Works! Thank you so much.